# How to run loop through rows in Range(A & Row)?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I need to optimize my code to avoid creating a new module every time.

How can I create a loop that changes the row number? For example, first run the code using row 1 (I1, H1 and M1) then row 2 (I2, H2 and M2) and so on.

```vb
Function Email()
Dim iMsg, iConf, Flds

Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set Flds = iConf.Fields

With Flds
    schema = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
    .Item(schema & "sendusing") = 2
    .Item(schema & "smtpserver") = "XXXXXXX"
    'Configura a porta de envio de email (porta de saída)
    .Item(schema & "smtpserverport") = XXXX
    .Item(schema & "smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item(schema & "sendusername") = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    .Item(schema & "sendpassword") = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    .Item(schema & "smtpusessl") = True
    .Update
End With

With iMsg
    .To = Sheets("Data").Range("I5").Value
    .From = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    .CC = Sheets("Dados").Range("H5").Value
    .Subject = Sheets("Data").Range("K5").Value
    .Sender = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    .HTMLBody = Sheets("Data").Range("M5").Value`
    Set .Configuration = iConf
End With

Set iMsg = Nothing
Set iConf = Nothing
Set Flds = Nothing
End Function


Sub disparar()
    Email
    MsgBox "Success!", vbOKOnly, "E-mail Sent"
End Sub
```

Is it possible to do this?

I tried using ActiveCell and Range A1:A20.

---

Would this work?

```vb
Function Email()
Dim iMsg, iConf, Flds
Dim xrow As Integer

xrow = 1

Do Until IsEmpty(Range("A" & xrow))

    Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
    Set Flds = iConf.Fields

    With Flds
        schema = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
        .Item(schema & "sendusing") = 2
        .Item(schema & "smtpserver") = "XXXXXXX"
        .Item(schema & "smtpserverport") = XXXX
        .Item(schema & "smtpauthenticate") = 1
        .Item(schema & "sendusername") = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
        .Item(schema & "sendpassword") = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        .Item(schema & "smtpusessl") = True
        .Update
    End With

    With iMsg
       .To = Sheets("Data").Range("I" & xrow).Value
       .From = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
       .CC = Sheets("Data").Range("H" & xrow).Value
       .Subject = Sheets("Data").Range("K" & xrow).Value
       .Sender = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
       .HTMLBody = Sheets("Data").Range("M" & xrow).Value`
        Set .Configuration = iConf
    End With

    Set iMsg = Nothing
    Set iConf = Nothing
    Set Flds = Nothing
Loop
End Function


Sub send()
    Email
    MsgBox "Success!", vbOKOnly, "E-mail Sent"
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Either  `Range("A" & Row1)` or `Cells(Row1, 1)` or `Cells(Row1, "A")`

Comment: Thanks for replying, Chis Neilsen! But how do I specify on the loop that it needs to change Row1 to Row2 on all the Ranges,? Do I have to set a loop for every line where I define a Range?

Comment: Use `Cells(iRow, iColumn)` where `iRow` and `iColumn` are variables.

Comment: Thanks user10186832! So would something like this work? Sub disparar()

Dim xrow As Integer, n As Integer

xrow = 1 

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells("A" & xrow))
.... (not inserting the rest for lack of space)
   .To = Sheets("Data").Range("I" & xrow).Value
   .CC = Sheets("Data").Range("H" & xrow).Value
   .Subject = Sheets("Data").Range("K" & xrow).Value
   .HTMLBody = Sheets("Data").Range("M" & xrow).Value`
Loop
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using .Offset(iRow, iCol).

Something like this:

```
Set MyBaseRange = Sheets("Data").Range("I5")

For iRow = 0 to 100
   With iMsg
      .To = MyBaseRange.Offset(iRow,0).Value
      .CC = MyBaseRange.Offset(iRow,1).Value
      .Subject = MyBaseRange.Offset(iRow,2).Value
      .HTMLBody = MyBaseRange.Offset(iRow,3).Value
   Set .Configuration = iConf
   End With

   ' Do Work

Next iRow
```